# Is there any age limit to be the Prime Minister of Pakistan in their Constitution?

Tags: constitution, democracy, pakistan

Is there any age limit to be the prime minister of Pakistan?

I have searched on the internet but couldn't find an answer. Is there any specific clause in the Pakistan's constitution that restricts the age of the Prime Minister?

Answer (score 9):

> Is there any age limit to be the Prime Minister of Pakistan in their Constitution?

According to Pakistan's constitution, the Prime Minister of Pakistan must be above 25 years of age.

Reference: [Constitution of Pakistan](http://www.pakistani.org/pakistan/constitution/part3.ch2.html)

Comment: Thanks for linking to the Constitution. But I don't want to read it all. Could you maybe include the number of the article or section of the Constitution used for reference.

Comment: [This section](http://www.pakistani.org/pakistan/constitution/part3.ch2.html#143) states the 25 year minimum age to be a member of parliament. I couldn't find any mention of any additional requirement to be a PM

Answer (score 0):

25 years is age limit for national and provincial assembly members while PM minimum age is 35 years. Just Google and you will find that.

Comment: Your answer seems correct. Can you back it up with some references? "Just Google and you will find that." is not really a good reference as people receive different results based on many factors such as language, location.